# Anytime changes are made on a form, an automatic email will be sent

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript, lotus, lotus-formula

Hi how do I make this be a automatic email notification? Right now its a manual via clicking a button.

Manual Button Code:

```
Sub Click(Source As Button) 
    Dim db As NotesDatabase 
    Dim doc As NotesDocument 
    ' get the database 
    Set db = New NotesDatabase( "", "LotusScript.nsf" ) 
    ' create a new document in the database 
    Set doc = New NotesDocument( db ) 
    ' set the new document's form so it'll be readable as a mail memo 
    doc.Form = "Memo" 
    ' set the new document's subject 
    doc.Subject = "Change Notification" 
    ' set the new document's body 
    doc.Body = "This Email is to notify you that changes has been made." 
    ' mail the new document 
    Call doc.Send( False, "Lekhwair Alatan" ) 
End Sub
```

[image: Sample Email Notification]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this automatically you can use exactly the same code.

You just have to put it in the **"PostSave"- Event of your form**.

I just don't get, why you need to open a specific database to do this. I would use CurrentDatabase for that.

In addition: I would use a NotesRichtextitem and add a **Doclink** to it, so that the user can instantly open the document by clicking the link in the mail:

```
Sub PostSave( Source as NotesUIDocument )
    Dim ses as New NotesSession
    Dim db As NotesDatabase 
    Dim doc As NotesDocument 
    Dim body as NotesRichtextItem
    ' get the database 
    Set db = ses.CurrentDatabase
    ' create a new document in the database 
    Set doc = New NotesDocument( db ) 
    ' set the new document's form so it'll be readable as a mail memo 
    doc.Form = "Memo" 
    ' set the new document's subject 
    doc.Subject = "Change Notification" 
    ' set the new document's body 
    Set body = New NotesRichtextitem( doc, "Body" )
    Call body.AppendText( "This Email is to notify you that changes has been made." )
    Call body.AddNewLine(1)
    Call body.AppendText( "Click here to open document --> " )
    Call body.AppendDocLink( Source.document, "Click me" )
    ' mail the new document 
    Call doc.Send( False, "Lekhwair Alatan" ) 
End Sub
```

TAKE CARE: You cannot use this code in your Button, as there "Source" is the button and not the current document. You'd need 1 more line of code and one change:

```
Dim ws as New NotesUIWorkspace ' this line at the very top
....
Call body.AppendDocLink( ws.CurrentDocument.document, "Click me" ) 'this instead of Source.document
```

Comment: Hi Torsten, thanks for you answer. Can I what are these lines for? Call body.AppendText( "Click here to open document --> " )
    Call body.AppendDocLink( Source.document, "Click me" )

Comment: How can I make this without a button. For example, I open a document, edit then clicked saved. An automatic email will be sent.

Comment: Did you READ my answer? `just put it in the "PostSave"- Event of your Form`. And if you wanna know, what the lines are for: Did you [rtfm](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_9.0.1/basic/H_NOTESRICHTEXTITEM_CLASS.html)?: `In addition I would use a NotesRichtextitem and add a Doclink to it, so that the user can instantly open the document by clicking`

Comment: Thanks Torsten! it's all working now. If you won't get mad and you have the best way. How do I send to multiple recipients? and is there a way to replace the sender's name? (LAlatan@qwerty.com)

Comment: As long as you read my answer and try to understabd before you ask I will never get mad... ;)

Comment: Hint: Sending to multiple recipients and replacing the sender's name are new questions. StackOverflow strongly discourages the use of comment threads to ask new questions. If you want answers for those things, you should create new questions -- but first, you should do a search. I am very certain that both of those topics have already been asked and answered before.